# VS Code not using words in document as suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

Perhaps I misunderstand what is means for VS Code to "use words in document" for suggestions, but I often have long words or identifiers that I'd like to use completion for, but they don't show up (probably because they aren't fully defined as code identifiers).

Note: I already made sure that "Use words" was checked in the preferences.

Second question: is it possible to get VS Code to automatically use the only suggestion on Ctrl-Space (if there is only one possible completion) so there's no need for Tab or Enter?

Comment: Hi Mike, check VS Code's Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Suggestions. Likely it's configurable.

Comment: I did. I checked "Use Words". In fact it was already checked.

Comment: Your hypothesis re: code id's is likely correct, in recent memory I've only seen suggestions for var and function names. Fairly new to VS Code myself, but I've installed various "intellisense" and "intellicode" and language-specific "snippet" extensions from the Extensions -> Marketplace. Perhaps there's an available extension for this?

Comment: I looked around, but nothing yet. One problem is I want the antithesis of "intelli" as in not intelligent -- like Emacs dynamic completion which just grabs any word without trying to understand the document. If there was a "DumbSense" extension that would help. All I can find are the "intelli", "super-intelli" and "ludicrous-intelli" extensions.

Comment: LOL I also wish auto-suggest would work when I'm typing commented text